# Google maps doesnt display polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a code:

```
tripCoordinates=[];

var coords[[37.772323, -122.214897],[21.291982, -157.821856],[-18.142599, 178.431]];
for(var i=0;i<coords.length;i++){                                           
   tripCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][0],coords[i][1]));
  }

  console.log(tripCoordinates);
  var tripPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: tripCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  tripPath.setMap(map);
```

and my problem is that google maps don't display that data on the map if I add new google.maps.LatLng(58.20554,23.58522) then that works, but with a looped array, that won't work, any suggestions?

Is it even possible to show data in this way?

Comment: Can you put your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry i dont know how do use it.

Comment: Try to unzoom the map. Can you see the drawing at a different location than intended?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cjupr903/    but not working there

Comment: nope, i  cant see drawing nowhere.

Comment: I can see the triangle when i replace the coordinates with yours in google's example code here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javacript error with [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkakm2xq/1/) (once I fix it so it works):
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

on this line:

```
var coords[[37.772323, -122.214897], [21.291982, -157.821856], [-18.142599, 178.431]];
```

should be:

```
var coords = [[37.772323, -122.214897], [21.291982, -157.821856], [-18.142599, 178.431]];
```

Then it works [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkakm2xq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
tripCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][0],coords[i][0]));
```

The second `coords[i][0]` should be `coords[i][1]`

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var coords = [
    [37.772323, -122.214897],
    [21.291982, -157.821856],
    [-18.142599, 178.431]
  ];

  tripCoordinates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    tripCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]));
  }

  console.log(tripCoordinates);
  var tripPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: tripCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  tripPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: i changed that, but still not displaying lines.